# XMPP Component indicating presence

Tags: xmpp, components

I have an XEP-0114 based XMPP component that works fine with the Openfire server. Ejabberd however complains about it.
First thing it does (after having authenticated) is to indicate presence. It does so by sending this:

```
<presence from="tictactoe.komogvind.dk"/>
```

I get this reply

```
<presence type="error" to="tictactoe.komogvind.dk" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
    <error code="400" type="modify">
        <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
</presence>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: components don't have to send a presence to the server. Maybe ejabberd does not like this. Can you send other stanzas from your component?

Comment: Everything else works...I would just like to use presence to indicate if the component is ready to accept work or not. Maybe I'll have to find another solution.

Comment: the server does not care about the presence from your component. The from attribute is not required because the server stamps it. You can try to add a to attrib and set the value to your server domain. Maybe this helps.